# Nonrectangular tensor encountered

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, tensors

I am trying to solve a system of equations which characteristic matrix:

```
K = {{1/2, -(1/8), 0, -(1/8), -(1/4), 1/8, -(1/4), 1/
8, -(1/4) (-2 + xΓ) xΓ, 
1/12 (-2 + xΓ), 
1/4 (2 + (-2 + xΓ) xΓ), 
1/12 (-1 - xΓ)}, {-(1/8), 1/2, 1/8, -(1/6), 1/
8, -(1/4), -(1/8), 0, 
1/12 (1 - 2 xΓ), -(1/4) + xΓ - 
 xΓ^2/2, 1/12 (-1 + 2 xΓ), 
1/2 (-1 + xΓ)^2}, {0, 1/8, 1/2, 1/
8, -(1/4), -(1/8), -(1/4), -(1/8), 
1/4 (2 + (-2 + xΓ) xΓ), (
2 - xΓ)/
12, -(1/4) (-2 + xΓ) xΓ, (
1 + xΓ)/12}, {-(1/8), -(1/6), 1/8, 1/2, 1/8, 1/
12, -(1/8), -(1/3), 1/6 (1 - 2 xΓ), 
1/6 (3 - 4 xΓ), 
1/6 (-1 + 2 xΓ), -(1/4) + (2 xΓ)/3}, {-(
1/4), 1/8, -(1/4), 1/8, 1/2, -(1/8), 0, -(1/8), 
1/4 (-1 - xΓ^2), (1 + xΓ)/12, 
1/4 (-1 + xΓ^2), (2 - xΓ)/12}, {1/
8, -(1/4), -(1/8), 1/12, -(1/8), 1/2, 1/8, -(1/4), 
1/6 (-1 + 2 xΓ), -(xΓ^2/2), 
1/6 (1 - 2 xΓ), 
1/4 (-1 + 2 xΓ^2)}, {-(1/4), -(1/8), -(1/4), -(1/8), 
0, 1/8, 1/2, 1/8, 1/4 (-1 + xΓ^2), 
1/12 (-1 - xΓ), 1/4 (-1 - xΓ^2), 
1/12 (-2 + xΓ)}, {1/8, 
0, -(1/8), -(1/3), -(1/8), -(1/4), 1/8, 1/2, 
1/12 (-1 + 2 xΓ), 1/4 (-1 + 2 xΓ^2), 
1/12 (1 - 2 xΓ), -(xΓ^2/
 2)}, {-(1/4) (-2 + xΓ) xΓ, 
1/12 (1 - 2 xΓ), 
1/4 (2 + (-2 + xΓ) xΓ), 
1/6 (1 - 2 xΓ), 1/4 (-1 - xΓ^2), 
1/6 (-1 + 2 xΓ), 1/4 (-1 + xΓ^2), 
1/12 (-1 + 2 xΓ), 
1/4 (4 k + 3 (1 + (-1 + xΓ) xΓ)), 
1/4 (1 - 2 xΓ), 
1/4 (-1 + 4 k - 3 (-1 + xΓ) xΓ), 
0}, {1/12 (-2 + xΓ), -(1/4) + xΓ - 
xΓ^2/2, (2 - xΓ)/12, 
1/6 (3 - 4 xΓ), (1 + xΓ)/
12, -(xΓ^2/2), 1/12 (-1 - xΓ), 
1/4 (-1 + 2 xΓ^2), 1/4 (1 - 2 xΓ), 
3/4 (1 + 2 (-1 + xΓ) xΓ), 
1/4 (-1 + 2 xΓ), 
1/2 (-1 - 3 (-1 + xΓ) xΓ)}, {1/
4 (2 + (-2 + xΓ) xΓ), 
1/12 (-1 + 2 xΓ), -(1/
4) (-2 + xΓ) xΓ, 
1/6 (-1 + 2 xΓ), 1/4 (-1 + xΓ^2), 
1/6 (1 - 2 xΓ), 1/4 (-1 - xΓ^2), 
1/12 (1 - 2 xΓ), 
1/4 (-1 + 4 k - 3 (-1 + xΓ) xΓ), 
1/4 (-1 + 2 xΓ), 
1/4 (4 k + 3 (1 + (-1 + xΓ) xΓ)), 
0}, {1/12 (-1 - xΓ), 1/2 (-1 + xΓ)^2, (
1 + xΓ)/12, -(1/4) + (2 xΓ)/3, (
2 - xΓ)/12, 1/4 (-1 + 2 xΓ^2), 
1/12 (-2 + xΓ), -(xΓ^2/2), 0, 
1/2 (-1 - 3 (-1 + xΓ) xΓ), 0, 
3/4 (1 + 2 (-1 + xΓ) xΓ)}}
```

After I obtain the inverse of part of the matrix:

```
Kinv = Inverse[K[[5 ;; 11, 5 ;; 11]]]
```

and I try to get the solution vector as

```
UU = Dot[Kinv , ( {
{P/2},
{0},
{P/2},
{0},
{0},
{0},
{0}
} )]
```

I get a message `Dot::rect: Nonrectangular tensor encountered. >>`, even though I obtain a solution (which is way too messy to see if it makes any sense). How do I inspect this system? Is there a function I can use to see if `KK` is built properly? I don't see any errors while performing the inverse.

Comment: Not nearly enough information here to answer the questions.

Comment: What would be needed? Should I edit the post and add the entire matrix?

Comment: What is `KK` and what does it mean to be "built properly"?  Also, what are `Kinv` and `P`?

Comment: I added K, but it looks really ugly in text. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: I guess you forgot to `Clear@P`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get the same error. I can't add the error because I'm limited with the number of characters.

Comment: The issue was that @xzczd! P had a vector stored as a variable, but I haven't set anything to P and I have quit the kernel. Why is this happening?

Comment: Probably because you've done this unconsciously. A easy way to keep yourself away from this kind of mistake is to always keep an eye on the color of the variable. Usually a variable without any value stored in is blue, otherwise it's black. (There're exceptions of course, for example the `K` you used in your code, and that's one of the reasons they're not recommended to be used as user-defined variables.)

Comment: Common causes of unintended initialization: Dynamic output, such as `Manipulate` and other dynamic modules; init.m; initialization cells; and perhaps accidental forgetfulness as xzcxd just pointed out.

Comment: Yes, the color trick would have been useful! Now regarding the variables, what do people use normally? It was pointed out to avoid uppercase names. I got also to this problem because of restrictions on names.

Comment: Using variables starting with a lowercase letter is a good habit of course. But personally I think uppercase name isn't a scourge, they can be used at least in toy codes. You just need to keep the color issue in mind. (BTW, the color of all the built-in function is black. )

Answer (score 3):

The question is not clear. However, I will state the assumptions and try to answer.

Assumption:

1. `Kinv` is the inverse of the matrix `K`
2. When you refer to `KK` you
   meant the matrix `K`

Answer:

The matrix `K` is of dimension `12X12`, which can be checked using `Dimensions[K]`. The inverse of the matrix will also be of dimension `12X12`. While taking the dot product, you are multiplying the matrix with another matrix of `7X1`. Hence, there is inconsistency in the dimensions which does not allow the dot product.

Few suggestions:

1. Do not use variable names with single letter capital letters. There might be some in-built function with the same name. For example `D`. In general it's a good practice to start all user-defined functions with small letter.
2. Consider simplifying the equations.
3. While posting a question give the complete MWE. Think from the reader's perspective and state all necessary but minimal lines of code.

**Edit**
The code works absolutely fine, after your edit! There is nor error or warning message. Tested in Mathematica 10.3. If you use `Simplify` you will get simpler expressions. The final answer comes out to be

> {{P + P/(4 k)}, {0}, {P + P/(4 k)}, {0}, {P/(4 k)}, {0}, {P/(4 k)}}

You should be able to replicate.

Comment: You're right, I modified the question accordingly, I missed one important part when editing the last question.

Comment: The code works absolutely fine, after your edit! There is no error or warning. I am using Mathematica 10.3

Comment: I had a wrong value of P (stored a vector). But I still fail to see why that happened!

Comment: I just found where in the code I was setting P... my stupid mistake... :/